# Pass json data to servlet (doPost) with Jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, aem

i'm learning about calls to ajax so i'm trying to get the value of ('#abcd') (a html select). I'm using this line:

> abcdVal = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value

When this value change i must store his value in a var like abcdVal for pass to servlet with:

> var data = {"text" : abcdVal};

```
j("#mybutton").click(function(){    
    j.ajax({method: 'POST',
        url: "/bin/company/repo",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data, 
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
            j("#demo").html('');
            j('#demo').html(result);
        }});
});
```

i got the value and put in response as a text plain, but in html page i see:

> [{"text":null,"value":10}]

Instead of [{"text":(selected value of html select),"value":10}]

i doing something wrong then i pass the data to servlet. how must i pass this var correctly?

---

My code

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var abcdVal;
j(document).ready(function(){
   //get a reference to the select element
  //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
  j.ajax({
      url: '/bin/company/repo',
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data){
        //clear the current content of the select
        j('#abcd').html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option
        jQuery.each(data, function(text, value){
            j('#abcd').append('<option id="' + value.value + '">' +         value.text + '</option>');
        });
      },
      error:function(){
        //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
        j('#abcd').html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
      }
});
j("#abcd").change(function(){
    var combo = document.getElementById('abcd');
    if(combo.selectedIndex<0)
        alert('No hay opcion seleccionada');
    else 
        abcdVal = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
        alert('La opcion seleccionada es: '+combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value);
});
var data = {"text" : abcdVal};
alert(data);
j("#mybutton").click(function(){    
    j.ajax({method: 'POST',
        url: "/bin/company/repo",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data, 
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
            j("#demo").html('');
            j('#demo').html(result);
        }});
});
})
</script>
```

Servlet code

```
@Override
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
        String text = (String) request.getParameter("text");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        TidyJSONWriter json = new TidyJSONWriter(writer); 
        try 
        {   
           json.array();
           //loop through your options and create objects as shown below 
           json.object();
           json.key("text");
           json.value(text);
           json.key("value");
           json.value(10);
           json.endObject();
           //end your array 
           json.endArray();     
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       response.getWriter().write(writer.toString());      // Write response body.  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this changes for solve my problem:

> 1) In ajax call change method: POST by type: 'POST'.
>
> 2) Add even.preventDefault() before call to ajax for dont use submit by default.
>
> 3) Change the form i handled data request. If i dont pass a form i need do this for retrieve request parameter like @Sabya explain.
>
> 4) Handle json inside of success (ajax) for show selection of html select.

So the code is the next:

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var abcd = document.getElementById("abcd");
var selection = abcd.options[abcd.selectedIndex].value
j(document).ready(function(){
   j.ajax({
          url: '/bin/company/repo',
          dataType:'JSON',
          success:function(data){
             jQuery.each(data, function(text, value){
             j('#abcd').append('<option id="' + value.value + '">' + value.text + '</option>');
        });
      },
      error:function(){
        //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
        j('#abcd').html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
      }
   });
   j("#abcd").live('change',function(){
      var combo = document.getElementById('abcd');
      if(combo.selectedIndex<0)
        alert('no option selected');
      else 
        selection = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
   });

   j('form').on('submit', function(e){
      event.preventDefault();
      j.ajax({type: 'POST',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "/bin/company/repo",
         dataType: 'JSON',
         data: JSON.stringify({ "text": selection }), 
         success:function(data){
            jQuery.each(data, function(text, value){
                 j('#demo').html('');
                 j('#demo').html(value.text);
            });
         }}); 
   });
})
</script>
```

Servlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,       SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        TidyJSONWriter json = new TidyJSONWriter(writer); 
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String data = buffer.toString();
        try 
        {   
           JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new String(data));
           json.array();
           //loop through your options and create objects as shown below 
           json.object();
           json.key("text");
           json.value(jsonObj.get("text"));
           json.endObject();
           //end your array 
           json.endArray();
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.write(writer.toString());

}
```

Comment: Probably the code can be more clean but this is a solution - @Sabya

Answer (score 0):

Use .live() in place of .change() because you select element is dynamic.

```
j("#abcd").live('change', function(){
    var combo = document.getElementById('abcd');
    if(combo.selectedIndex<0)
        alert('No hay opcion seleccionada');
    else 
        abcdVal = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
        alert('La opcion seleccionada es: '+combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Comment: i did, thanks. do you know about how solve this problem? i'm thinking now i will must use a BufferedReader or something for read data in servlet. - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: i got null when i did request.getParameter("text"); - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?? @jmhdez

Comment: use .live in place of on ..as written in answer .. and check text parameter in servlet ..it should not be null now .. @jmhdez

Comment: Same -> null. I believe the problem is when i send data or rescue him. Bad sintax or wrong way - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: Declare data like this.. var data = {text : abcdVal} and then check.. @jmhdez

Comment: i did before and got null too. - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: first confirm that abcdVal has the real value what you want and then use it with .live() ..

Comment: i inserted: <option id="9" selected="selected">This is default</option> with selected="selected" for put a default select option and then alert(abcdVal) and got var undefined. - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: maybe only in the .live i get in abcVal his value

Comment: if i change" data: data, " (ajax call) by "data: {"text" : "hi"}, " show me null too i dont understand.  i tryed with '{"text" : "hi"}' too with the same result. - @Brijesh Bhatt

Comment: check my solution - @Brijesh Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the servlet call in network panel of chrome and check the Request-Header and/or form data ?

Not sure about your problem in javascript , but if you are getting an NPE in your servlet , that might be because you are not POSTing it as a form data and trying to retrieve it from request parameter.

Accessing the data sent as a Request Payload is a little different than accessing the form data.

The following snippet might help you in case you find that you are POSTing the JSON to the servlet as a **Request Payload**.

```
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String requestData = buffer.toString();

        //TODO: Retrieve required fields from this requestData string .
```