# How to send data to java servlet via ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I have a UI where I have some check-boxes in form of on of switch I have a button also when user clicks on that button the on click event I am running an ajax to send that data to my back-end and save into my database.

**My UI**

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'DisplayImage',
    'method': 'POST',
    'data': formToJSON(),
    'success': function(data) {

    },

    complete: function() {

    },
    'error': function(err) {

    }
  })

  function formToJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify({
      ImageData: tableData,
    });
  };
})
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="margin: 20px 0">
        <div class="card-header">Counter A</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">CounterA1.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success" >
        <span class="slider round" ></span>
      </label>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">CounterA2.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="card-header">Counter B</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">CounterB1.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="card-header">Counter C</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">CounterC1.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn"> Go</button>
```

I have tried  converting all this to a JSON like this

```
var tableData = {"Counter A": {"Name": "CountA1.jpg","IsActive.jpg":"Y"}}
```

but there are two issues :-

- It says not a valid JSON when I tried to enter `Counter B` data as well
- When I am sending this to back end in my `doPost` it `consoles`  null

I don't know what is going wrong. Do I need to change my approach?

**Ajax Code**

```
  $("#btn").on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({ 
        'url': 'DisplayImage', 
        'method': 'POST', 
        'data' : formToJSON() ,
        'success': function(data){ 
        }, 
        complete: function(){
        },
        'error': function(err){ 
        } 
    })
    function formToJSON() 
    {
         return JSON.stringify({ImageData:tableData,});
    };
})
```

**Servlet doPost**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String imageData = request.getParameter("ImageData");
    System.out.println(imageData);

}
```

I thought of this idea as I am lacking to approach, I just want to know some approaches to this problem. My database table in which this data is going to be inserted looks like:

[image: This]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass json data to servlet (doPost) with Jquery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469366/pass-json-data-to-servlet-dopost-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @DushyantTankariya No that didn't help as I am lacking in JSON, as you can check my UI I have some tree structure for `Counter A` two Images for `Counter B` one Image so what will be the JSON, that is  where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want "counterA" and "counterB" in JSON array then you need to create JSON like below.

```
var tableData = [{ "Counter A": [{ "Name": "CountA1.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"Y" } ,{"Name": "CountA2.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"N"}]},
                 { "Counter B": { "Name": "CountB1.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"Y" } } ];
```

Or you can convert your json array as

```
var tableData = [ { "Counter": "Counter A", "Name": "CountA1.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"Y" }  ,
                  { "Counter": "Counter A", "Name": "CountA2.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"N" } ,
                  { "Counter": "Counter B", "Name": "CountB1.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"Y" }  ];
```

To insert JSON data in the database I would suggest you do some google.
But for small understanding, I've Posted below code and statement which will help you.

> Create Model class,
>   Ex: Counter.java

```
private String counter;
private String img;
private String flag;

public void setCounter(String counter){this.counter=counter;}
public String getCounter(){return this.counter;}

//Same getter and setter methods for img and flag.
```

> Now get back to your main class

```
 JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(request.getParameter("ImageData"));
 JSONObject obj;
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 List<Counter> lstCounter = new ArrayList<Counter>();
 Counter counter = new Counter();

 //Create Loop which iterates your jArray
{
     JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse( < jArray[iterator.next()] >  ) //Here you need to parse the each your JSON and convert one by one in jsonobject
     Ex: { "Counter": "Counter A", "Name": "CountA1.jpg", "IsActive.jpg":"Y" } as your first line you can extract the first row.

     //Store the row in Model Counter as a list
     counter = new Coutner();
     counter.setCounter( <read data from json array> );
     //same thing for img and flag then add to lstCounter
    lstCounter.add( counter);
}
```

After completion of the loop, you will have the listArray Which is ready to store in DB same as normal insertion operation.

Comment: Hey but counter A as two Images `CounterA1.jpg` `CounterA2.jpg`, that is causing issue,you have only one in your code

Comment: I've updated the JSON as you have `CounterA1.jpg` and `CounterA2.jpg`

Comment: Hey i have a doubt  as per your JSON at back-end `{"ImageData":[{"Counter A":[{"Name":"CountA1.jpg","IsActive.jpg":"Y"},{"Name":"CountA2.jpg","IsActive.jpg":"N"}]},{"Counter B":{"Name":"CountB1.jpg","IsActive.jpg":"Y"}}]}` I am getting it like this, now How can i excess this values to insert it into my database as you can check my picture of database

Comment: So You can change the JSON array in such a way that it is flexible for you to store data in the database.
I've updated the answer again you can look at it.

Comment: hey that is fine your both the parts are correct, but can you help me with with some java code (dummy) How can i insert this json to my db, I know about normal insertion, but how to do this with this json

Comment: I've again updated the answer, But I want you to do some google about storing jsonArray values in the database. I've updated only content which is helpful for your understanding about How to store JSON Data in DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194743/discussion-between-dushyant-tankariya-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 0):

You can use data tag in jquery like below
data: {
                    Data1 : Data1,
                    Data2 : Data2,
                    Data3 : Data3, }

Comment: Yup I know that, but issue is I have to bind that data like for `Counter A` I have two images how will i bind that in my jquery code

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream())
String imageData = scanner.nextLine();
```

And check if it's still null

Comment: it works fine but my issue is still there, I am not able to create a apecific JSON Above it is only for counter A, can yo just help me with JSON

Comment: What if: { "Counter": "Counter A",
                "Name": "CountA1.jpg",
                "IsActive.jpg":"Y"
              }

Comment: Hey can you please help me with some java code so that I can insert it inside my db please